# Missing method body

Tags: java

I am answering on questions. And I have a problem with one Java question. Can you help me guys? The question is: Explain the concept of casting using the code below.  State why this code will result in an error and how this can be rectified.

```
public class PayrollSystem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee me = new FullTimeEmployee();
me.CalcSalary();
me.CalcBonus();

}

}

class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee{
public void CalcBonus()
}


class Employee {
    public void CalcSalary()
}
```

As the code now works well, what would be the answer to the question: "Explain the concept of casting using the code below"? The code that I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((FullTimeEmployee)me).CalcBonus();
```

As `CalcBonus` method is in `FullTimeEmployee` class, `Employee me` reference can not invoke that method, But `Employee me` holding a reference of `FullTimeEmployee` object which is derived class object, so it needs to casr it to derived class before invoking the `CalcBonus` method.

---

And also complete your method by adding parentheses `{}` after each method what you have missed! :)

Comment: wow everyone focusing on the missing {} while this is the real correct answer. +1

Comment: @BigMike that is just typing mistake and i am sure :)

Comment: agree. I'd add some interface usage example to make the answer more complete.

Comment: I feel that would be better approach but he asked different question ;)

Comment: And I would be greatful if you modify my answer and add some value :)

Comment: I added {} in both CalcBonus and Employee, byt still shows error in me.CalcBonus(); part. And when I replace me.Calcbonus to ((FullTimeEmployee)me).CalcBonus(); it shows even more errors.

Comment: And what are those error? Infact it doesnt showing any error for me

Comment: It compiles perfectly with the cast. What kind of errors are you having ?

Comment: Ohhh, now it works. Don't know what's happened. Yes, thanks. But what would be the answer for the question: "Explain the concept of casting using the code below", the code that I provoded.

Answer (score 2):

method body means {}

you have not included in CalcBonus and CalcSalary

```
public class PayrollSystem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee me = new FullTimeEmployee();
me.CalcSalary();
me.CalcBonus();

}

}

class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee{
public void CalcBonus()
{
}
}


class Employee {
    public void CalcSalary()
{
}
}
```

Comment: I added {} in both CalcBonus and Employee, byt still shows error in me.CalcBonus(); part. What should I do next?

Comment: I think your problem is solved now.If you find any problems then feel free to ask

Comment: As the code now works well, what would be the answer to the question: "Explain the concept of casting using the code below"? The code that I provided.

Comment: @user3755831 post another question clearly mentioning your requirement with codes

Comment: No, it's me. But the question about code is answered, but the question: "Explain the concept of casting using the code below" has not been answered. I need that answer.

Answer (score 0):

change to -->

```
public void CalcBonus(){
//some code
}


 public void CalcSalary(){
//some code
}
```

You have not defined the body of your method.